# How do I position the axis frame inside a figure without changing the size of the figure? [Python, matplotlib]

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to create a video of many figures, so I need the axis to remain steady across multiple, independent figures. However, the y-axis changes scale, so the framing of the axis keeps moving as the ticklabels change. I'm trying to manually tell matplotlib exactly what size the whole figure should be and tell it exactly the position of the axis within the figure, but it's not working properly.

Here's what a base figure looks like:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig=plt.figure(figsize=(8,4),facecolor=(0.5,0.5,0.5))
ax=fig.add_subplot()
ax.plot([5,10],[800,900])
plt.show()
```

[image]

Here is one way for how I'm trying to change it if I want the axis frame to start at left=0.5, bottom=0.5, width=0.2, and height=0.2. I've tried many different ways, and all have failed, so this is illustrative of what I'm trying to do:

```
fig=plt.figure(figsize=(8,4),facecolor=(0.5,0.5,0.5))
ax=fig.add_axes((0.5,0.5,0.2,0.2))
ax.plot([5,10],[800,900])
plt.show()
```

[image]

Now, I want it to look more like this so that the black box of the axis frame will be in the exact same position for every figure, and each figure will be the exact same size. That way, when I make it an animation, the black frame won't be jerking around. (Obviously, I wouldn't make the buffer that big in the real video.)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [ax.set_position](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.0/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_position.html).

If your ax box initially occupies the full figure, you can create a new size relatively to the old one, for example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8, 4), facecolor=(0.5, 0.5, 0.5))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
bbox = ax.get_position()
new_bbox = (bbox.x0+0.40, bbox.y0+0.40, bbox.width*0.5, bbox.height*0.5)
ax.set_position(new_bbox)
ax.plot([5, 10], [800, 900])
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Urgh, yes, this works. I had tried this, but apparently, Jupyter Notebook's inline plt.show() doesn't respect this and only gives the tight layout. When I save the figure from your code, however, it works like you show. When I was trying my actual video code, Jupyter Notebook was doing the same thing and not respecting the set_position, but when I saved the figure, I had overwritten the position apparently with bbox_inches='tight', making it look the same as Jupyter's inline show. Two separate problems, both of which acted in the exact same way, making me think it was one bigger problem. Ugh.